# win32com when parsing Outlook 2010. Instance showed up instead of the name/subject of the folder/message

Tags: python, outlook, outlook-2010, win32com

I had this problem in the afternoon. The code works perfectly fine in the morning. I am very confused why it happened.

```
import win32com.client  
outlook = win32com.client.dynamic.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
folder = (outlook.Folders)[1]
print(folder)
```

the result is this:

```
<win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Outlook 14.0 Object Library.MAPIFolder instance at 0x37167984>
Process finished with exit code 0
```

in the morning, I could get the name of the folder by simply

`print(folder)`

However, I don't know what settings I changed, I now need to put ".Name" after folder in order to get the folder's name

```
print(folder.Name)
```

Why did this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know why it did happen, [but correct syntax is folder.Name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa171690%28v%3Doffice.11%29)